# Move array element to variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have created an array using php, piped it over to JavaScript using `JSON_parse`, so far so good.

Problems is that I must now extract a column from this JS array and store it in a simple character-variable. This must surely be in the Javascript 101 but I can't get it to work and I can't find the proper syntax anywhere.

`currentVid = jArray[3];` to retrieve data(here from the third row) does not work and I am at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Anyone who can help me out? So I need the proper syntax to copy an array-element(let's say third row, first element) to a variable(char).

Here is the code btw:

```
<?php

$videoList = [];

$arrayNumber = 0;

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "PPAUser";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "PPADB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT video_link FROM videolinks";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// output data of each row into internal array 

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $videoList[$row['cat']][] = array( 
         'video_link' => $row['video_link']);
        }
    }

$conn->close();

?>

<script>
    function setVideoPrev() {

    var currentVid = document.getElementById("iFrame").src;

    var jArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($videoList ); ?>');

    currentVid = jArray["video_link", 3];

    document.getElementById("iFrame").src = currentVid;
}
</script>
```

The line `currentVid = jArray["video_link", 3];` does not do the trick but I tried many many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED. Based on comments, answer was edit.

Looks like it should be `jArray[YOUR_CATEGORY][0].video_link`. `YOUR_CATEGORY` it's what in `$row['cat']`

Comment: Thanks but I get 'cannot read property '3' of undefined...

Which is weird because in the debugger I see :

jArray: Object
"": Array[4]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object

Comment: looks like you have array of arrays. try to access `jArray[0]` first and `console.log(jArray[0])` it.

Comment: That gets me : 

undefined
index.php:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefinedsetVideoPrev @ index.php:21onclick @ index.php:165

Comment: I've tried your example, looks like it should be `jArray[YOUR_CATEGORY][0].video_link`. YOUR_CATEGORY it's what in `$row['cat']`

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll work on that a bit more tonight. So far it doesn't solve the problem.  When I debug after the jArray has been created I see this :
 

jArray: Object
   "": Array[4]
      0: Object
       video_desc: "Massada - Sageru 2015"
       video_id: "1"
       video_link: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/fGMFRVrCK68"
       video_type: "URL"
__proto__: Object

etcetera. 

I don't get why the "array" is displayed.

Comment: YES! Got the bastard! 

Recoded as follows(I hope the formatting works, I'm new here, sorry) :

SQL " 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $videoList[$row['video_id']] = array( 
          'video_id' => $row['video_id'],
      'video_desc' => $row['video_desc'],
      'video_type' => $row['video_type'],
      'video_link' => $row['video_link']);
  }
    }

    var jArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($videoList ); ?>');
  
    currentVid = jArray[3]["video_link"];


Thank you very much for the assistence, I needed the push in the right direction.

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid syntax for accessing arrays. Try doing something like this instead:`currentVid = jArray["video_link"][3]`. If you're unsure of what your data looks like, just print it out in console.